# Return all page iFrames without id element

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I tried this the intuitive way with both JavaScript and jQuery, with no dice for either.

```
document.GetElementsByTagName('iframe');
```

got me:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method
>   'GetElementsByTagName'

and `$('iframe')`
got me `undefined`.

Is an iframe an element? Is there a way to do this?

I'm trying to return all the page iframes.

Thank you.

Comment: you need to include jQuery to use `$('iframe')`.

Comment: `window.frames` is an option. It collects both `iframe` and `frame` elements. However, that can be countered with  a simple `window.frames[iterator].tagName === "IFRAME"` check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function needs a lower case g like so `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')` . Yes, iframe is a tag. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName

Comment: thank you :) this is great, and it is returning all document iframes, but not iframes that are children. Should I be able to do the same to find the child?

Comment: I'm a little confused what you mean by iFrame children. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I'm looking for an iframe that's within a specific iframe.

Answer (score 2):

An `iframe` is just a normal element.

You need to observe the correct case of [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) (lowercase leading `g`, the DOM API uses camelCase, not PascalCase).

Also, for jQuery, `$('iframe')` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function getFramesWithNoId() {
    var result = [];
    var frames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
        if (!frames[i].id) {
            result.push(frames[i]);
        }
    }
    return(result);
}
```

You can see in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Uxsyg/

Comment: I don't think the OP meant to literally get `iframe`s without `id` attribute.

Comment: I took the title of the OP's post for what it says, but maybe they meant something different.  Who knows?